# LVDS pin configuration

Tags: lvds

I'm trying to drive a LVDS display. However, there are pins that I don't know about their functions and how to apply signal to it:

- DIMO (Output): Backlight CABC controller signal output
- CABC_EN0 & CABC_EN1 (Input): CABC H/W enable

> When CABC_EN=”00”, CABC OFF.
> When CABC_EN=”01”, user interface image.
> When CABC_EN=”10”, still picture.
> When CABC_EN=”11”, moving image.
> When CABC off, don’t connect DIMO, else connect it to backlight.

I tried looking up on the Internet but there are no instructions whatsoever about this.

Which configurations should I use for CABC_EN?

Thank you very much in advance.

Comment: As per your description, you connect the pins based on what mode you want the display to be in, and that depends on what material you intend to show on the display. So we have no idea how you should connect them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What CABC does is basically to adjust the backlight dynamically, depending on the image to be displayed, to save power. For example, if the image is almost totally white (i.e. brightest) the internal display controller may suggest the driver to decrease the backlight intensity *(via DIMO - **D**imming **O**utput)* while it increases the pixel illumination intensity, effectively to reach the same overall illumination while decreasing overall power consumption as the backlight on its own consumes most of the power.

So if you really need this functionality then think about applying the respective signals.

CABC_EN inputs require logic-level signals (can be 5V or 3.3V generally, but refer to the datasheet). If you don't need this functionality then just tie those inputs to ground.